# How to vertically align two UILabels within one line?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

[image]

I am trying to put two `UILabel`s within one line: one `UILable` on left side, with text left-aligned, one `UILabel` on right side, with text right-aligned. Please see above image. They have different font sizes.

I used below auto layout constraints:

```
 let labelHorizontalConstrains = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|-20-[nameLabel]-15-[birthDeathDateLabel]-20-|",
        metrics: nil,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += labelHorizontalConstrains
```

But the result shows that they are not vertically aligned: The left `UILabel` is lower than the right `UILabel`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `centerYAnchor` constraint.

```
birthDeathDateLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

However, if you want it aligned with the base of the text, you should use a `UIStackView`.

```
let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [nameLabel, birthDeathDateLabel])
stackView.alignment = .firstBaseline
stackView.axis = .horizontal
// Add other stackview properties and constraints
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a leading constraint and a height constraint to the right label. add a trailing and height constraint to the left label. then specify an equal widths constraint. also on the right label add the distance from the left label with a trailing constraint and for the left label add a leading constraint how far you want it from the right label.. much easier on storyboard. you could also use fit equally.. I can't remember the actual code, but it might have refreshed your memory. if I was too add that sort of constraint I would do it on a skeleton storyboard.